# Automatic commits to Github

Tags: xml, git, github, cron

I have a project folder that is updated multiple times per day from a remote process with new xml log files.

Is it possible to schedule a regular automatic commit (cron?) from the local project to Github and allow remote users access to the github repo to pull the new files?

Comment: Why are you using a Git repository for log files?  That doesn't seem like a good fit, since you don't need to keep history for the files.

Comment: The history would be useful

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of articles on making a task to be run with cron which you already suggested in your question. [Here’s just one](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/101288/how-to-schedule-tasks-on-linux-an-introduction-to-crontab-files/amp/).

What you want could be achieved with these git commands in a script

```
find . -name "*.log" | xargs git add
git commit -m “<whatever you want, maybe $(date)?>”
git push origin <branch name>
```

Comment: what if there aren't new *.log files to add (nothing to commit)?

Comment: The command won’t add any files, you won’t be able to commit without any files, you won’t be able to push anything without a commit. Alternatively you could implement conditionals in the script you’re running.